# VSTO Deployment MSI File System.Memory.dll error

Tags: excel, windows-installer, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to build an MSI installer for my little excel application, following the official microsoft guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022#ConfigureRegisitry

Everything works fine, so I can build and rebuild without any problems, unless I make a small change to the installer, e.g. change the name of the manufacturer or similar, or even only closing the project and Visual Studio and reopening it. Then I always get this error:

------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'project Setup' ------

ERROR: Unable to find source file 'C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\project Setup\System.Memory.dll' for assembly 'System.Memory.dll', located in '[TARGETDIR]'

------ Pre-build validation for project 'project Setup' completed ------

Any ideas?

I tried to rebuild the project Setup. This always fails. Even though nothing has changed, neither on the actual project, nor on the Setup project (the MSI installer).